# How to aggregate entities into group based on edge data?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregate

I have high volume of undirected edges stored in mongodb and need to make an aggregation into groups.

example document:

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('604065fe7e8146a4eeb7d7af'),
  'ent1': `id_of_entity1`,
  'ent2': `id_of_entity2`
}
```

E.g.

- a - b
- a - d
- b - c
- f - e
- g - h
- h - i

would produce 3 groups:

1. [a, b, c, d]
2. [f, e]
3. [g, h, i]

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: can you add the actual document structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start of by saying Mongo is -NOT- a graph db. This usually means it will not be my first choice for any graph related problems.

What you're asking for can be done in Mongo but definitely not efficiently as it requires you to iterate over the entire collection multiple times. I will attach the code sample in case you do want to use it but again I recommend you rethink the `db` choice, the data structure choice or any change you could do to make this more approachable.

With that said here is the code, the approach is first to `$group` the entire collection so we can iterate over it. Then start clustering the documents into groups by seeing if the array intersection is not 0.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ents: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      clusters: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$ents",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $size: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$value",
                        as: "val",
                        cond: {
                          $gt: [
                            {
                              $size: {
                                "$setIntersection": [
                                  "$$val",
                                  [
                                    "$$this.ent1",
                                    "$$this.ent2"
                                  ]
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            0
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                $map: {
                  input: "$$value",
                  as: "val",
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $gt: [
                          {
                            $size: {
                              "$setIntersection": [
                                "$$val",
                                [
                                  "$$this.ent1",
                                  "$$this.ent2"
                                ]
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          0
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$setUnion": [
                          "$$val",
                          [
                            "$$this.ent1",
                            "$$this.ent2"
                          ]
                        ]
                      },
                      "$$val"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    [
                      "$$this.ent1",
                      "$$this.ent2"
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Hs4rD0oueS)

Comment: That is a great answer and one of the solutions. I am aware that mongo is not a graph db, yet the data is stored there, which is probably a mistake in the first place. Would it make sense to just do all this programmatically rather than querying the db?

Comment: I would personally just do it with code yes because you can create your own "BFS/BDS" logic and make this process much leaner (and with indexes on `ent1` and `ent2` fields probably somewhat efficient), the reason i gave the "mongo-y" way is for 1. what was asked and 2. to show how versatile mongo is.